# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure despite adding certifcates in jdk trustore

Tags: tls1.2, fatal-error

I am building a rest api that calls and returns the response of another api using web client builder .The api being called uses tls protocol . I have added the root, intermediate and the certificate to the jdk trustore path and restarted my machine. The certificates exist however I continue to get this error.

This is my bean :

@Bean

```
public WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder(){
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                    HttpClient.create()
                            .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext())
            ))
            .build();

}
```

Can someone suggest what am i missing

Resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure